# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents()' on a null object reference

Tags: android-activity

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589715/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-dispatchcancelp). My code is different but the cause may be the same. I thought my code was simpler and might be helpful for finding the culprit.
First, the crash that happens only **occasionally** (i.e., the code works fine most of the time):

```
Class: java.lang.NullPointerException
 Stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:4499)
        at android.view.View.cancelPendingInputEvents(View.java:18456)
        at android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(Activity.java:4657)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4636)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:753)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api16Impl.b(ActivityCompat.java:0)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.k(ActivityCompat.java:0)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:258)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:175)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
```

The code that causes the crash **occasionally**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FooActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mode", "manage");  
intent.putExtra("pro", true);
launcherFooActivity.launch(intent);
```

The following is launcherFooActivity:

```
   final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcherFooActivity = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                try {
                   ...
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                   ...
                }
            });
```

Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this crash?